# finding specific pattern in string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a String "Everything is fine", and I want to find a string that starts with "Eve" and ends with "ing", middle letters could be any letter. How can I do it in python?

Comment: I would use `s.find('Eve')` and `s.find('ing')`.

Comment: Did you do _any_ research? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/843953

Comment: Take a look at [regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp). However, you should also read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: both condition (starting with 'Eve' and ending with 'ing') should be satisfied, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your string

```
my_string = "Everything is fine"
```

You can do the following

```
my_string.split(" ")
for word in my_string.split(" "):
    if word[:3] == "Eve" and word[-3:] == "ing":
        print(word)
    else:
        pass
```

Also you can assign all these words in a list like that

```
my_words = []
my_string.split(" ")
for word in my_string.split(" "):
    if word[:3] == "Eve" and word[-3:] == "ing":
        my_words.append(word)
    else:
        pass
```